# What does compressing an equation mean?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, transport-equation

> Solve $$u_t + u_x +7u = 0$$

After using an integrating factor to reduce the ODE to a transport equation PDE I got $$\left(e^{7x}\right)u_t + \left(e^{7x}\right)u_x + 7\left(e^{7x}\right)u = 0$$

The solution then says to compress the equation to $$\left(ue^{7x}\right)_t + \left(ue^{7x}\right)_x = 0$$ which is in a transport equation with $v = u\left(e^{7x}\right)$.

Can you explain how they compressed the equation and what that means?

Comment: The point is to use the product rule in reverse, so that the third term can be absorbed into the derivative of some products. The integrating factor method for first order linear ODE works the same way.

Comment: Thank you,this makes sense now.